# How to create conditional error bars in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to display conditional error bars, for example, when I ran this I see the error bars for all values.

```
d <- qplot(cyl, mpg, data=mtcars)
d + stat_summary(fun.ymin=min,fun.ymax=max,geom="errorbar")
```

I would like to display the above error bars only if N > than a specified value. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you could build function factories for the `fun.ymin` and `fun.ymax` arguments that only give the value if the input length exceeds some number. The only downside is though that it has to return some value, so you'll get a warning about that.

```r
library(ggplot2)

nmax <- function(n) {
  n <- force(n)
  function(x) {
    if (length(x) >= n) {
      max(x)
    } else {
      NA_real_
    }
  }
}

nmin <- function(n) {
  n <- force(n)
  function(x) {
    if (length(x) >= n) {
      min(x)
    } else {
      NA_real_
    }
  }
}

d <- qplot(cyl, mpg, data=mtcars)
d + stat_summary(fun.ymin = nmin(8), fun.ymax = nmax(8), geom = "errorbar")
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_errorbar).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

If you find that specifying N two times is too cumbersome / error prone, you can also make regular functions that take n as an argument and pass `fun.args`:

```
nmax2 <- function(x, n) {
  if (length(x) >= n) {
    max(x)
  } else {
    NA_real_
  }
}

nmin2 <- function(x, n) {
  if (length(x) >= n) {
    min(x)
  } else {
    NA_real_
  }
}

d <- qplot(cyl, mpg, data=mtcars)
d + stat_summary(fun.ymin = nmin2, fun.ymax = nmax2, fun.args = list(n = 8), geom = "errorbar")
```

Comment: Alternatively, pass a subset of the data to `stat_summary` using the `data` argument. For example use `data = . %>% group_by(cyl) %>% filter(n() >= 8)`

Comment: @Axeman

Hi! I am trying to use this solution. However, instead of passing a fixed argument to my functions I would like to pass the value of the dots that I am plotting. This is my code: 
`ggplot(data=chr1, aes(x=x_values0, y=AF))+ geom_point(aes(col=color), size=2)+
stat_summary(aes(fun.ymin = ymin(AF, sdPopHetAF), fun.ymax = ymax(AF, sdPopHetAF)), geom = "errorbar")`
AF and sdPopHetAF are variables from chr, the dataframe indicated in the beginning. However, it is not detecting this variables and not working. How can I solve this?

Comment: @Jeni, it's better if you ask a new question, and show a reproducible example of your problem. I don't see anything obviously wrong, other than your code has `chr1` as data, but you say your data is `chr`.